# How to configure Users permissions in Windows Server 2008 R2 by command line?

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, user-accounts

I have to create about 800 users in our Windows S 2008 R2 and I'd like to make a few settings with them.

1. Create user: `net user Joe 1mb4pASs /add /fullname:"John Smith" /passwordchg:no /comment:"no comment"`
2. Set never expired password: `wmic useraccount where "Name='Joe'" set PasswordExpires=FALSE`
3. Add the user to two groups (like in the Members Of tab in the GUI)

   - Remote Desktop Users
   - (I translated it from hungarian, because the server) `Terminal Services - Computers` to enable the use of applications via webaccess

Step 3 is where I'm having problems. What command(s) should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `net.exe` in a very similar way to what you're currently doing:

`net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add domain\Joe`

You probably don't want to add users to the `Terminal Services Computers` group, though. That's used for Remote Desktop Services licensing when you have the GPO to enforce licensing based on group enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the DN (distinguished names of AD group and user)

[Add a member to a group in AD via command-line interface](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737130%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_cmd)

[Add a member to the local group via CLI](http://www.windows-commandline.com/2009/05/add-user-to-group-from-command-line.html)